# Error when using TimeDistributed layer with keras

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I want to build a deep learning network with keras(version 2.1.3) to analyse video stream frame by frame. I tried to use TimeDistributed layer and got my network like this:

```
video = keras.Input(shape=(32,150,150,3), name='video')
cnn = InceptionV3(weights = 'imagenet', include_top=False,pooling='avg')
cnn.trainable = False
frame_features = layers.TimeDistributed(cnn)(video)
video_vector = layers.LSTM(256)(frame_features)
predictions = Dense(101,  activation='softmax')(video_vector)
model = Model(inputs=video, outputs=predictions)
```

when I built the network and I got an error:

```
ValueError: Variable batch_normalization_1/moving_mean/biased already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope? Originally defined at:

  File "D:\install\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
  File "D:\install\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "D:\install\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
```

Who can please tell me how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Curiously, I don't get this error in Keras 2.1.0 with the code you posted. Isn't it a case of resetting your kernel to eliminate any possible preexisting InceptionV3 models?

Comment: It seems that it's a problem of my tensorflow. I upgraded my tensorflow from version 1.2.0 to 1.4.0 then the problem was fixed. I'm not familiar with the TimeDistributed layer but it's probably that this layer would call the CNN model several times and then cause the reuse problem. Anyway thanks for answering :)